# How to append a value to a list which is in a different python file?

Tags: python

I have 2 python files. The first has some code and a global list. The second file is a script and I want to append a value to the global list depending on the user input. When I am in the context of the script the value is appended, but when I check the list's value after running the script the appended value is not there. 
How would I ensure that the appended value actually gets added?

Comment: Can you share the code and the file samples?

Comment: Why don't you create a function in the second script and call it in the first script?

Comment: access the list with ``module.L`` instead of ``from module import L`` and you willl modify the original list instead of a copy.

Comment: Another user who thinks that a program is a set of files, because it is not, is a set of functions, variables, classes, etc. that interact. So there should only be one main file and in your case the other should be a secondary file, so you should import the other things into the main file using imports.

Comment: @ThatBird I have tried that but the appended value does not persist.

Comment: Why don't you share some code also?

Comment: " the appended value does not persist" => if you expect it to persist between scripts execution then I'm afraid you expect too much indeed.